Conda having difficult time installing packages on Linux with Miniforge3
Here is the text below, I'm not sure what I did wrong.
Conda Version 24.5.0
Device: BeagleyAI using Debian as OS

> \`Channels:
> conda-forge
> defaults
> Platform: linux-aarch64
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed
> Channels:
> conda-forge
> defaults
> Platform: linux-aarch64
> Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
> Solving environment: failed
>
> LibMambaUnsatisfiableError: Encountered problems while solving:
> nothing provides requested mkl_random 1.2.2\*\*
> nothing provides requested mkl_fft 1.3.1\*\*
> nothing provides requested mkl-service 2.4.0\*\*
> nothing provides requested mkl 2021.4.0\*\*
> nothing provides requested jasper 1.900.1\*\*
> nothing provides requested intel-openmp 2021.4.0\*\*
> nothing provides openssl \>=1.0.2p,\<1.0.3a needed by python-3.7.1-hd75c258_1001
> package ncurses-6.3-h2f4d8fa_0 requires libgcc-ng \>=10.2.0, but none of the providers can be installed
>
> Could not solve for environment specs
> The following packages are incompatible
> intel-openmp 2021.4.0\*\*  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
> jasper 1.900.1\*\*  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
> libgcc-ng 9.3.0\*\*  is installable with the potential options
> libgcc-ng 9.3.0 would require
> libgomp 9.3.0 h8ab15db_17, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 9.3.0 would require
> libgomp 9.3.0 h8e86211_14, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 9.3.0 would require
> libgomp 9.3.0 h8e86211_15, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 9.3.0 would require
> libgomp 9.3.0 he1ea209_19, which can be installed;
> libgomp 9.3.0\*\*  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> libstdcxx-ng 9.3.0\*\*  is requested and can be installed;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3\*\*  is installable with the potential options
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> python \>=3.10,\<3.11.0a0 *\_cpython with the potential options
> python \[3.10.2|3.10.4|...|3.9.13\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0  with the potential options
> libzlib 1.2.11 would require
> zlib 1.2.11 \_1014, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.11 would require
> zlib 1.2.11 \_1012, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.11 would require
> zlib 1.2.11 \_1013, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.12 would require
> zlib 1.2.12 \_0, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.12 would require
> zlib 1.2.12 \_1, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.12 would require
> zlib 1.2.12 \_2, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.12 would require
> zlib 1.2.12 \_3, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.12 would require
> zlib 1.2.12 \_4, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.13 would require
> zlib 1.2.13 \_4, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.13 would require
> zlib 1.2.13 \_5, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.2.13 would require
> zlib 1.2.13 \_6, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.3 would require
> zlib 1.3 \_0, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.3.1 would require
> zlib 1.3.1 \_0, which can be installed;
> libzlib 1.3.1 would require
> zlib 1.3.1 \_1, which can be installed;
> pypy3.8 \[7.3.8.* |7.3.9. \] with the potential options
> pypy3.8 \[7.3.8|7.3.9\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk \>=8.6.12,\<8.7.0a0  with the potential options
> tk 8.6.12, which can be installed;
> tk 8.6.13 would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.13,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk \[8.6.11|8.6.12\] would require
> zlib \>=1.2.12,\<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
> tk 8.6.14 would require
> zlib \>=1.2.13,\<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
> pypy3.8 \[7.3.11|7.3.9\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.13,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.8 7.3.9 would require
> zlib \>=1.2.12,\<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
> pypy3.9 \[7.3.8. |7.3.9. \] with the potential options
> pypy3.9 \[7.3.8|7.3.9\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk \>=8.6.12,\<8.7.0a0  with the potential options
> tk 8.6.12, which can be installed;
> tk 8.6.13, which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk \[8.6.11|8.6.12\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk 8.6.14, which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.9 \[7.3.11|7.3.9\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.13,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.9 7.3.9 would require
> zlib \>=1.2.12,\<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
> tk \>=8.6.12,\<8.7.0a0  with the potential options
> tk 8.6.12, which can be installed;
> tk 8.6.13, which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk \[8.6.11|8.6.12\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk 8.6.14, which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python \[3.10.10|3.10.11|...|3.9.19\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.13,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.8 7.3.11. , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.9 7.3.11. , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python \[3.10.0|3.10.1|3.10.2|3.9.7\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python \[3.10.5|3.10.6\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.12,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python_abi 3.10. *\_cp310, which can be installed;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> python_abi 3.7.* *\_cp37m, which can be installed;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> python_abi 3.7 \_pypy37_pp73, which can be installed;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> pypy3.7 \>=7.3.7 , which requires
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python_abi 3.7 \_pypy37_pp73, which can be installed;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> python_abi 3.8.* *\_cp38, which can be installed;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> libstdcxx-ng \>=9.4.0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> python \>=3.7,\<3.8.0a0  with the potential options
> python \[3.6.7|3.7.1|3.7.2|3.7.3\] would require
> readline \>=7.0,\<8.0a0 , which can be installed;
> python \[3.6.7|3.7.1\] would require
> openssl \>=1.0.2p,\<1.0.3a , which does not exist (perhaps a missing channel);
> python \[3.7.10|3.7.9\] would require
> python_abi 3.7 \_pypy37_pp73, which can be installed;
> python \[3.7.10|3.7.5|3.7.6|3.7.8|3.7.9\] would require
> python_abi 3.7.* *\_cp37m, which can be installed;
> python \[3.7.10|3.7.12\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python_abi 3.7.* *\_cp37m, which can be installed;
> python 3.7.12 would require
> pypy3.7 7.3.7.* , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python_abi 3.7 *\_pypy37_pp73, which can be installed;
> python \[3.7.3|3.7.6\] would require
> python_abi \* \_cp37m, which can be installed;
> python \[3.7.10|3.7.11\] conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> python \[3.10.6|3.7.13|3.8.13|3.9.12|3.9.13\] would require
> zlib \>=1.2.12,\<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
> python \[3.10.3|3.10.4|3.7.13|3.8.13|3.9.11\] would require
> sqlite \>=3.38.0,\<4.0a0  with the potential options
> sqlite \[3.38.2|3.38.3|3.38.4|3.38.5\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.38.3|3.38.5|...|3.39.3\] would require
> zlib \>=1.2.12,\<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
> sqlite \[3.39.2|3.39.3|3.39.4\] would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.12,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.40.0|3.41.2|...|3.46.0\] would require
> libzlib \[\>=1.2.13,\<2.0.0a0 |\>=1.2.13,\<2.0a0 \], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite 3.38.0, which can be installed;
> sqlite 3.38.2, which can be installed;
> sqlite \[3.40.0|3.40.1\] would require
> zlib \>=1.2.13,\<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
> sqlite \[3.41.1|3.41.2|3.45.3\] would require
> zlib \>=1.2.13,\<2.0a0 , which can be installed;
> python \[3.10.10|3.10.11|...|3.9.19\] would require
> zlib \>=1.2.13,\<1.3.0a0 , which can be installed;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> python \>=3.8,\<3.9.0a0  with the potential options
> python \[3.10.6|3.7.13|3.8.13|3.9.12|3.9.13\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python \[3.10.3|3.10.4|3.7.13|3.8.13|3.9.11\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python \[3.10.10|3.10.11|...|3.9.19\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python \[3.8.0|3.8.1\] would require
> python_abi \* \_cp38, which can be installed;
> python \[3.8.10|3.8.12|...|3.8.8\] would require
> python_abi 3.8.* *\_cp38, which can be installed;
> python \[3.10.2|3.10.4|...|3.9.13\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python 3.8.12 would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python_abi 3.8.* *\_cp38, which can be installed;
> python \[3.10.10|3.10.11|...|3.9.19\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python \[3.8.11|3.8.12|3.8.8\] conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> matplotlib-base 3.4.3 would require
> libstdcxx-ng \>=10.2.0 , which conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> mkl-service 2.4.0*  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
> mkl 2021.4.0  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
> mkl_fft 1.3.1  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
> mkl_random 1.2.2  does not exist (perhaps a typo or a missing channel);
> ncurses 6.3  is installable with the potential options
> ncurses 6.3 would require
> libgcc-ng \>=10.2.0  with the potential options
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_10, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_11, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_12, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_13, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_14, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_15, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_16, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_3, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_4, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_5, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_6, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_7, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_8, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.3.0 would require
> libgomp 10.3.0 h26189b7_9, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.4.0 would require
> libgomp 10.4.0 h2e586c5_16, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.4.0 would require
> libgomp 10.4.0 h2e586c5_17, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.4.0 would require
> libgomp 10.4.0 h9a8471f_18, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 10.4.0 would require
> libgomp 10.4.0 h9a8471f_19, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.1.0 would require
> libgomp 11.1.0 h3322914_3, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.1.0 would require
> libgomp 11.1.0 h3322914_4, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.1.0 would require
> libgomp 11.1.0 h3322914_5, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.1.0 would require
> libgomp 11.1.0 h3322914_6, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.1.0 would require
> libgomp 11.1.0 h3322914_7, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.1.0 would require
> libgomp 11.1.0 h3322914_8, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_10, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_11, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_12, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_13, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_14, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_15, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_16, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_8, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.2.0 would require
> libgomp 11.2.0 hf1cc4e7_9, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.3.0 would require
> libgomp 11.3.0 h9c27daf_18, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.3.0 would require
> libgomp 11.3.0 h9c27daf_19, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.3.0 would require
> libgomp 11.3.0 hab8075d_16, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.3.0 would require
> libgomp 11.3.0 hab8075d_17, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 12.1.0 would require
> libgomp 12.1.0 h3242a24_16, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 12.1.0 would require
> libgomp 12.1.0 h3242a24_17, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 12.2.0 would require
> libgomp 12.2.0 h607ecd0_18, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 12.2.0 would require
> libgomp 12.2.0 h607ecd0_19, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.4.0 would require
> libgomp 11.4.0 h4e10709_0, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.4.0 would require
> libgomp 11.4.0 h4e10709_1, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.4.0 would require
> libgomp 11.4.0 h4e10709_2, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.4.0 would require
> libgomp 11.4.0 h4e10709_3, which can be installed;
> libgcc-ng 11.4.0 would require
> libgomp 11.4.0 h4e10709_4, which can be installed;

> pypy3.9 7.3.13 would require
> xorg-libx11 \>=1.8.6,\<2.0a0 , which can be installed;
> pypy3.9 \[7.3.13|7.3.15\] would require
> xorg-libx11 \>=1.8.7,\<2.0a0 , which can be installed;
> python 3.9.18 would require
> pypy3.9 7.3.15.\* , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python 3.10.0 would require
> sqlite \>=3.37.2,\<4.0a0  with the potential options
> sqlite \[3.38.2|3.38.3|3.38.4|3.38.5\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.38.3|3.38.5|...|3.39.3\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.39.2|3.39.3|3.39.4\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.40.0|3.41.2|...|3.46.0\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite 3.38.0, which can be installed;
> sqlite 3.38.2, which can be installed;
> sqlite \[3.40.0|3.40.1\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.41.1|3.41.2|3.45.3\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite 3.37.2, which can be installed;
> python 3.9.12 would require
> sqlite \>=3.38.2,\<4.0a0  with the potential options
> sqlite \[3.38.2|3.38.3|3.38.4|3.38.5\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.38.3|3.38.5|...|3.39.3\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.39.2|3.39.3|3.39.4\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.40.0|3.41.2|...|3.46.0\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite 3.38.2, which can be installed;
> sqlite \[3.40.0|3.40.1\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> sqlite \[3.41.1|3.41.2|3.45.3\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python 3.9.7\*\*  is installable with the potential options
> python 3.9.7, which can be installed;
> python 3.9.7, which cannot be installed (as previously explained);
> python \[3.10.0|3.10.1|3.10.2|3.9.7\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> python_abi 3.9\*\*  is installable with the potential options
> python_abi 3.9 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> python_abi 3.9 would require
> pypy3.9 7.3.\*  with the potential options
> pypy3.9 7.3.13, which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.9 \[7.3.13|7.3.15\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.9 \[7.3.8|7.3.9\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.9 \[7.3.11|7.3.9\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> pypy3.9 7.3.16 would require
> xorg-libx11 \>=1.8.9,\<2.0a0 , which can be installed;
> pypy3.9 7.3.9, which can be installed (as previously explained);
> readline 8.1\*\*  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> sqlite 3.37.0\*\*  is not installable because there are no viable options
> sqlite 3.37.0 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> sqlite 3.37.0 would require
> libzlib \>=1.2.11,\<2.0.0a0 , which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk 8.6.11\*\*  is installable with the potential options
> tk \[8.6.11|8.6.12\], which can be installed (as previously explained);
> tk 8.6.11 conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> xorg-libx11 1.7.2\*\*  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported;
> zlib 1.2.11\*\*  is not installable because it conflicts with any installable versions previously reported.

